# How to get today's inserted documents in Couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I want to get all the documents which were inserted today in couchbase. My document doesn't has any `createdAt` timestamp. Can someone please guide on how this can be achieved without adding any timestamp to document?

Answer (score 3):

There are several N1QL date functions you can use to insert the current timestamp in a range of formats. You can find out more here:

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html#fn-date-clock-local

Comment: thanks...but I don't want to insert any timestamp in the document. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: See if this helps https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77108/couchbase-get-document-creation-date

Comment: If not modified from creation or you want all modified documents. You can use following query. NOW_STR("2019-01-01") gives todays date.

    SELECT  META(t).id 
    FROM default 
    WHERE META(d).cas >= STR_TO_MILLIS(NOW_STR("2019-01-01"))*1000000;